# nfs equivalant services in smb?

Tags: nfs, cifs

I want to know if there are nfs equivalant services in smb(windows server).
for example nfs to mount volume on nfs client nfs server (in case of nfs3) should be running daemon like rpc.mountd,quota,nlm-nsm.What services are running of windows server to support client side share mapping?and if there are any specific service runs for NTLM or Kerberos authentication?

Comment: completely not getting what you are asking.

Comment: Frank,my question is,what are nfs equivalent services on CIFS?
or What services a windows server must run to act as a windows file server.

Answer (score 0):

Everything CIFS is handled in-kernel on the Windows NT family of operating systems. This includes exporting the share as well as (most of) the authentication and authorization stuff..

Comment: you can even see the activity in the system (pid=4) process when cifs/smb is doing somthing

Comment: Daniel,I have found one workstation services which must run on windows server to provide smb services.What else?

Comment: Rather, the question is what you're trying to accomplish. This site is mostly for practical questions, not theoretical debate. Windows consists of many absolutely essential services. It's best to just not stick your nose in there.